# Call Web Service with input parameter in Excel

Tags: xml, excel, vba, web-services

I'm starting to work with Web Services

I am trying to send a xml request for a web service in vba but i get a error at `oXmlHttp.send xmlInput`: MSXML “The system cannot locate the resource specified”

```
Sub testar()

Dim xmlInput As String xmlInput = "<admitirTrabalhador><trabalhador>11111111111</trabalhador><modalidadeContratoTrabalho>E</modalidadeContratoTrabalho><dataInicioContrato>2016-12-26</dataInicioContrato><dataFimContrato>2016-12-26</dataFimContrato><retribuicao>540.60</retribuicao><diuturnidades>1</diuturnidades></admitirTrabalhador>"

Dim oXmlHttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 
Set oXmlHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

oXmlHttp.Open "POST", "https://pregfct.seg-social.pt/ws/gfct/admitirTrabalhador?wsdl", False, "2222222222", "XXXXX" oXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 

oXmlHttp.send xmlInput

Debug.Print oXmlHttp.responseText

Dim oXmlReturn As MSXML2.DOMDocument60 
Set oXmlReturn = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60 
oXmlReturn.LoadXML oXmlHttp.responseText


End Sub
```

How do I send request XML as an input parameter to the admitirTrabalhador method?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: First, I could not get the wsdl from https://pregfct.seg-social.pt/ws/gfct/admitirTrabalhador?wsdl
So that could be a problem.
Second, I don;t think you should POST to  url that is supposed to return you WSDL. 
In any case, may be you want to do a GET request on the WSDL before you POST to see if you can even get the WSDL.
Also Fiddler is your friend in these cases, it will tell you what is going on the wire

Comment: Indeed, I get the error "System can't...." because the URL is unreachable